# c++ cmd application: command to scroll terminal until current line is at the top?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, command-line, cout

I use `cout` to display some output in my c++ command line application. Now I find myself wishing to programmatically scroll the terminal window until the current line is all the way at the top (and previously output text is hidden out of view). I suspect there is a simple command to do that, but I just spent a lot of time googling and could not find it.

Is there a way to force the terminal to scroll to current location? If so, what is the syntax I should use?

Comment: Are you sure that you need to force that from your app? In Linux terminals you can just press Ctrl+L and it will scroll down like this, with any app. Maybe there's something similar on Windows too, I don't know. Maybe this Ctrl+L hint will help you with googling

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one can achieve this with [ANSI control sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences):

```
// System headers
#include <windows.h>

// Standard library C-style
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool EnableVTMode()
{
    // Set output mode to handle virtual terminal sequences
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode))
    {
        return false;
    }

    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, to activate ANSI sequences, in the `main` we just have to call once:

```
bool fSuccess = EnableVTMode();
```

Finally, since my terminal always stays at `30` lines of height, to scroll the terminal up and place the current line back at the top I do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) { cout << "\x0A"; }
cout << "\x1b[H";
```